# Problem while install ubuntu 12.04.3-server

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I try to install Ubuntu 12.04.3-server-i386 in my system. My system configuration is 256MB RAM, 80GB hard disk, Pentium 4 (2.40Gz). I have a DVD drive, I downloaded 12.04.3-server-i386.iso and burnt it on a CD and started installation.

The error I got:

> Your installation CD-ROM couldn't be mounted. This probably means that the CD-ROM was not put in the drive. If so you can insert it and try again
>
> Try again to mount the CD-ROM?
> Yes No

What shall I do now?

Comment: Copy the ISO image to the USB stick and attempt to install Ubuntu again.

Comment: User @Ramesh points out that this has been discussed in [this](http://www.mattkowalczyk.com/blog/?p=169) link.

Comment: @Ramesh I don't think that link is relevant actually, the OP was using a CD, not a USB.

Comment: @terdon, Thanks for letting me know.  I will be more careful in posting answers.

Comment: yeah, but basically both are concerned with mounting the ISO images only. So I thought that link might be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooting tips already? https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/boot-troubleshooting.html

Comment: I try boot from usb as well now I face same problem. As @Ramesh told I went through the link I try the commands in shell `mkdir /media/usb/` and `mount /dev/sdb /media/usb/` it gives me error invalid argument . I know sdb is my usb drive

Comment: I had this issue with cd installation, not usb, and Ramesh's link worked for me with the proper modifications. Instead, you mount /dev/cdrom /cdrom. The rest is the same. So, as Ramesh points out, the article is applicable to both scenarios (usb or cd install).